# Select attribute from node with XPath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a file with the following structure

```xml
<admin>
 <sampleName>Willow oak leaf</sampleName>
 <sampleDescription comment="Total genes">
  <cvParam cvLabel="Bob" accession="123" name="Oak" />      
 </sampleDescription> 
</admin>
```

I'm trying to get out the text "Total genes" after the sampleDescription comment, and I have used the following code:

```ruby
sampleDescription = doc.xpath( "/admin/Description/@comment" )
sampleDescription = doc.xpath( "/admin/Description" ).text
```

But neither work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doc.xpath` returns a NodeSet which acts a bit like an array. So you need to grab the first element

```
doc.xpath("//admin/sampleDescription").first['comment']
```

You could also use `at_xpath` which is equivalent to `xpath(foo).first`

```
doc.at_xpath("//admin/sampleDescription")['comment']
```

Another thing to note is that attributes on nodes are accessed like hash elements--with `[<key>]`

Answer (score 1):

might be a typo... have you tried `doc.xpath("/admin/sampleDescription/@comment").text`?

Comment: strange - how about `doc.css('sampleDescription[comment]').first['comment']`, otherwise, which Nokogiri and Ruby version do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because there's no Description element. As mentioned by Iwe, you need to do something like `sampleDescription = doc.xpath("/admin/sampleDescription/@comment").to_s`

Also, if it were me, I would just do `sampleDescription = doc.xpath("//sampleDescription/@comment").to_s`. It's a simpler xpath, but it might be slower.

And as a note, something that trips up a lot of people are namespaces. If your xml document uses namespaces, do `sampleDescription = doc.xpath("/xmlns:admin/sampleDescription/@comment").to_s`. If your doc uses namespaces and you don't specify it with `xmlns:`, then Nokogiri won't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
doc.xpath("//admin/sampleDescription/@comment").to_s
```

Comment: Note that `xpath` returns a nodeset, not a single node.